# Requests.py как сделать загрузгу/выгрузку файлов с прогрессбаром?

Tags: python, requests

У меня есть 2 функции `send_file()` и `get_file()`

Обе функции делают post запрос на сервер.

Все работает как надо, но мне хочется чтобы загрузка/выгрузка файлов сопровождалась прогрессбаром, желательно без дополнительных библиотек.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Для начала можно попробовать "погуглить". Только PYPI выдал мне 350+ различных библиотек, да я увидел что вы хотели это реализовать без доп библиотек, однако у библиотек есть исходный код в котором можно подсмотреть реализацию. А потом даже тут отвечали на подобныевопросы, в том числе и я: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1497337/Как-заполнять-progress-bar-по-мере-загрузки-файла/1497419#1497419

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как заполнять progress bar по мере загрузки файла?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1497337/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-progress-bar-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)